# How can I do something like if(typed key before if == "x")

Tags: c#

Ok so I am a noob at c# and want to do a simple quiz
Seeing that I have no idea to do an interface quiz yet,I tried a very simple one,something like this

```
Console.WriteLine("question");
Console.WriteLine("a" + " " + " " + " " + " " + "b" + " " + " " + " " + " " + "c");
Console.ReadLine();
 if (Console.ReadLine() == "a")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("comment");
            }
 else if (Console.ReadLine() == "b")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("comment");
            }
 else if (Console.ReadLine() == "c")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("comment");
            }
```

I know this is horrible,but I can't see any other method in doing a quiz at my current level
Until know,I wasn't understanding why it was letting me type the answer a 3 times,then I realized the readline does this
Can I do something in this simple way or I need to step up my programming skills?

Comment: Save the result of a `Console.ReadLine()` in a string variable and test against that?

Comment: You need to use a variable. Assign the return value of the first ReadLine to that variable, then test that variable against your constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Switch Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_switch.asp) which is neater
and save result of `Console.ReadLine()` into a [variable](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_variables.asp).

Multiple `Console.ReadLine()` will result in multiple ask for answer.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("question");
string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
switch (userChoice)
{
    case "a":
        Console.WriteLine("Your choice was a");
        break;
    case "b":
        Console.WriteLine("Your choice was b");
        break;
    case "c":
        Console.WriteLine("Your choice was c");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the result in a string variable and reference it:

```
string choice = Console.ReadLine();
if (choice == "a")
{
    Console.WriteLine("comment");
}
else if (choice == "b")
{
    Console.WriteLine("comment");
}
```

Comment: I did it like this,though I will probably switch to switch (hehe),thanks

Comment: @alii98 Sure that would be better; I just wanted to make the minimal amount of changes to get the concept across.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You missed this simple fact
when ever your program reach Console.ReadLine() it will read from console
what you can do is this

```cs
string str = Console.ReadLine();
if (str == "a")
{
    Console.WriteLine("comment");
}
else if (str == "b")
{
    Console.WriteLine("comment");
}
else if (str == "c")
{
    Console.WriteLine("comment");
}
```

And you know, as long as right side of your check statements are constant values it's better to use switch case statement
Then your code would be like this

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();
switch(str)
{
case "a":
    Console.WriteLine("comment");
    break;
case "b":
    Console.WriteLine("comment");
    break;
case "c":
    Console.WriteLine("comment");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 'for' loop to display a list of answers:

```
List<string> answers = new List<string>();

answers.Add("answer 1");
answers.Add("answer 2");
answers.Add("answer 3");

Console.WriteLine("question");

for (int i = 0; i < answers.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine((char)('a' + i) + "." + answers[i]);
```

With this code you'll be able to clear and fill the answer list for each question.

Comment: Why would anyone what to use a `for` loop for this? This isn't even a good example of implementing a `for` loop for this problem.